# ListView selecioint all checkboxes

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, android-adapter

I have method to selection all checkbox in listView and sometimes checkboxes does't work.
it happens when i scroll to last item and go back.

This metod call in activity:

```
public void setAllBoxesChecked(boolean value)
    {
        for(int i=0; i < lvSklepy.getCount(); i++)
        {
            View view = lvSklepy.getAdapter().getView(i, null, lvSklepy);

            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.cb_sklep);
            cb.setChecked(value);
        }
    }
```

adapter:
first item is checkbox on selection all checkboxes.

```
public View getView(int position,View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) 
    {
....
final CheckBox chboxShop = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb_sklep);

        if(position  == 0)
        {

            chboxShop.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) 
                {
                    Boolean blnObj = new Boolean(isChecked);

                    callOnClickListener(RES_CHECKBOX, blnObj, chboxShop);   
                }
            });
            rLayout = R.layout.ad_preferowane_sklepy;
        }
        else
        {
            final ImageLayout llImage = (ImageLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.il_image);

            chboxShop.setText(item.nazwaPelna);
            llImage.imageFromWeb(item.logoUrl);


        }
...
}
```

Comment: you need save Checked value in one list, and read from that in getView method.

Comment: i use "trick" add private boolean state to adapter. In activity add new item and remove last item from arraylist(adapter) then call notifyDataSetChanged. Adapter is refreshed and checbox set value from state

Answer (score 0):

In the XML file that has your list view layout add this code

```
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Lets say you have a Relative layout with text views -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/look_separator"
    style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" 

    />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/look_checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

  />
```